# python: how to access values in nested dictionaries using loops

Tags: python

Given the following dictionary in python.

```
dict = {'site1': {'status': 200}, 'site2': {'status': 200}, 'site3': {'status': 200}}
```

How can I iterate and access the values of a sub dictionary?

```
for sub in dict.items():
    print(sub["status"])
```

gives error: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Desired outcome:
print 3 strings indicating site status for each sub dict.

Comment: `for site_name, data in dict.items():`...

Answer (score 1):

`items()` returns a tuple of (key, value), so for loop should like this:

```
dct = {'site1': {'status': 200}, 'site2': {'status': 200}, 'site3': {'status': 200}}

for key, value in dct.items():
    print(value['status'])
```

Out:

```
200
200
200
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict.items()` returns iterable of tuple pairs `(key, value)`. In here you want to further index a *value*, so you should either do:

```
for sub in dict.values():
    print(sub["status"])
```

to iterate values only.

Or:

```
for key, sub in dict.items():
    print(sub["status"])
```

to unpack the tuple (that's what one usually does when dealing with `dict.items()`).

Of course you could also index the tuple first - `sub[1]["status"]` but it's not as readable.

---

PS You should never name your dicts just `dict` (nor lists `list`) - it's a build-in name used to denote the type. Changing it might introduce bugs later on.

Answer (score 1):

```
for sub in dict.values():
  print(sub)
#that will gives you list of dictionaries
{'status': 200} {'status': 200} {'status': 200}
```

Now to print key values

```
for sub in dict.values():
   print(sub['status'])
```